# How to execute multiple unix command through JSCH using same shell?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to execute multiple commands from on ssh through my java program. Based on execution result i need to execute some more commands on same shell. But when i tried to execute it is taking different shell. If any one knows the resolution is much appreciated.

Here is my code snippet

```
public class sshconnectionTest {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session;
    Channel channel;

    public Session openSession() throws Exception {

        if (null == session) {
            session = jsch.getSession("user", "hostname",
                    22);

            System.out.println("**************************************"
                    + session.isConnected());

            AESencrp aesEncrypt = new AESencrp();

            session.setPassword("pwd");
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect(10 * 1000);

        }
        return session;
    }

    public Channel openChannel(Session session) throws Exception {

        if (null == channel) {
            channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        }

        return channel;
    }

    public String getSession(String command1) throws Exception {

        try {

            session = openSession();
            channel = openChannel(session);

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command1);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            String readText = "";
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    readText = new String(tmp, 0, i);

                    System.out.print(readText);
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "
                            + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            // session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            sshconnectionTest sshcon = new sshconnectionTest();
            String command1 = " env | grep CCM;";
            String session = sshcon.getSession(command1);
            String command = "export SRL_FILE=/home/20140224/myfile.txt;";
            sshcon.getSession(command);
            sshcon.getSession("env | grep SRL;");
            sshcon.getSession("pwd");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a new session every time you call `getSession()`. This is why every command is being executed in a different shell, because it is a different shell.

Instead, get your session once in your `main()`, keep that object. Then re-use it.

You will need a different method other than `getSession()`, not to mention "get session" is not a good name for a method which is executing commands on a remote shell... ie. it's not just getting a session, but doing something else. This violates the principal of least astonishment, ie. each method should do one and only one thing.

Create a new method, say called: `executeRemoteCommand(String command)` and use that to execute your commands. You could either use `getSession()` once and store the session in an object that is accessible from every method, ie. an instance variable. Or you can pass your session into your `executeRemoteCommand()` method. So like: `executeRemoteCommand(Session session, String command)`.

Here is an example of how I have done this in the past (not going to pretend this code is perfect... but it should give you some ideas). This was used to send and receive files from a linux server via sFTP. With some modification, it could send just about any command to the remote shell you desire.

```
package com.somecompany.productfeed;

import net.snakedoc.jutils.ConfigException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class SFTP {

    // setup logger
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SFTP.class.getName());

    private JSch jsch;
    private ChannelSftp sftpChannel;
    private Session session;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String host;
    private int port;

    // singleton
    private volatile static SFTP instance = null;

    /**
     * Private constructor used in Singleton pattern.
     *     All variables populated via properties file upon 
     *     object instantiation. Since we only need FTP to one server,
     *     object variables are immutable after instantiation.
     * 
     * @throws ConfigException
     * @throws NumberFormatException
     */
    private SFTP() throws ConfigException, NumberFormatException {

        this.jsch = new JSch();
        this.username = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_USER");
        this.password = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_PASS");
        this.host = Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_HOST");
        this.port = Integer.parseInt(Config.getInstance().getConfig("SFTP_PORT"));

    }

    /**
     * Create or Return SFTP Object using Singleton pattern.
     * 
     * @return Singleton of SFTP Object.
     * @throws NumberFormatException
     * @throws ConfigException
     */
    public static SFTP getInstance() throws NumberFormatException, ConfigException {

        if (SFTP.instance == null) {

            synchronized (SFTP.class) {

                if (SFTP.instance == null) {

                    SFTP.instance = new SFTP();

                }

            }

        }

        return SFTP.instance;

    }

    /**
     * If connection is not already open/connected, open connection.
     * 
     * @throws JSchException
     */
    public void openConnection() throws JSchException {

        LOG.info("Opening SFTP Connection");
        if (null == getSession() || ! getSession().isConnected()) {

            setSession(jsch.getSession(this.username, this.host, this.port));
            getSession().setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            getSession().setPassword(this.password);
            getSession().connect();

            Channel channel = getSession().openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            setSftpChannel((ChannelSftp) channel);

        } else {

            LOG.info("SFTP Connection already open");

        }

        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

    /**
     * Closes connection.
     */
    public void closeConnection() {

        LOG.info("Closing SFTP connection");
        getSftpChannel().exit();
        getSession().disconnect();
        LOG.debug("SFTP Connection closed");

    }

    /**
     * Checks if SFTP Connection is open.
     * 
     * @return TRUE if connection is open, FALSE if connection is closed
     */
    public boolean isOpen() {

        if (getSession().isConnected()) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;

        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets SFTP Channel
     * 
     * @return SFTP Channel (<code>ChannelSftp</code>)
     */
    private ChannelSftp getSftpChannel() {

        return this.sftpChannel;

    }

    /**
     * Returns current <code>Session</code>
     * 
     * @return <code>Session</code>
     */
    private Session getSession() {

        return this.session;

    } 

    /**
     * Sets SFTP Channel (<code>ChannelSftp</code>)
     * 
     * @param sftpChannel Channel to set this object's <code>ChannelSftp</code>
     */
    private void setSftpChannel(ChannelSftp sftpChannel) {

        this.sftpChannel = sftpChannel;

    }

    /**
     * Sets current <code>Session</code>
     * 
     * @param session Sets this object's <code>Session</code>
     */
    private void setSession(Session session) {

        this.session = session;

    }

    /**
     * Pushes local file to remote location
     * 
     * @param local String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_local_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @param remote String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_remote_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @throws SftpException
     */
    public void push(String local, String remote) throws SftpException {

        LOG.info("Sending file: " + local + " to remote: " + remote);
        getSftpChannel().put(local, remote);
        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

    /**
     * Gets remote file to local location
     * 
     * @param remote String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_remote_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @param local String representation of filepath + filename (ex: /some_local_directory/somefile.txt)
     * @throws SftpException
     */
    public void get(String remote, String local) throws SftpException {

        LOG.info("Retrieving file: " + remote + " saving to: " + local);
        getSftpChannel().get(remote, local);
        LOG.debug("Success");

    }

}
```

Comment: I have done the same changes but still it takes different shell. It wont retain same shell.

Comment: if you are using the same connection, session and channel, then it will be the same shell. you are doing something wrong... :/  ... take a closer look how I did it. I set the private fields once, then leave them (including the jsch, channel, and session objects. this means, every time you use that same object, it's the same.